# How to initialize a vector of vectors in pre c++ 11 syntax?

Tags: c++, vector

I've read a significant number of questions and answers on this exact topic but none of them have helped me figure this out.

I have a vector of vectors being initialized using c++ 11 code like so:

```
return { {1,1,1}, {1,2}, {2,1}, {3} };
```

How can I convert this to pre-c++ 11 syntax in as few lines as possible?

Comment: Unfortunately, I guess you need to create a `vector`, thus another `vector`, fill the later a `push_back` at a time and push back it into the former, and so on with the others...

Comment: Convert your compiler to a C++11 compliant one :) Joking of course...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assignment or construction from an array is a straightforward option:

```
int temp[] = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3 };
std::vector<std::vector<int>> a(4);
a[0].assign(&temp[0], &temp[3]);
a[1].assign(&temp[3], &temp[5]);
a[2].assign(&temp[5], &temp[7]);
a[3].assign(&temp[7], &temp[8]);
```

Comment: That's very fragile code. It's very easy for a maintainer to inadvertently foul things up.

Answer (score 0):

The basic code looks like this. Faster alternatives can avoid repeated calls to `back()`, but this is the clearest way to see how it relates to your original.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> a;
a.push_back(std::vector<int>());
a.back().push_back(1);
a.back().push_back(1);
a.back().push_back(1);
a.push_back(std::vector<int>());
a.back().push_back(1);
a.back().push_back(2);
a.push_back(std::vector<int>());
a.back().push_back(2);
a.back().push_back(1);
a.push_back(std::vector<int>());
a.back().push_back(3);
return a;
```

Answer (score 0):

The key idea for writing maintainable code in C++03 (or C++98) is to **name** things. That's also a good idea in general, but it can conflict with ideal of reasonable conciseness. That is, it can easily become too verbose to be entirely painless.

With proper support one can then write code like

```
namespace my{
    using std::vector;

    vector< vector< int > >
        foo()
    {
        int const a0[] = {1,1,1};
        int const a1[] = {1,2};
        int const a2[] = {2,1};
        int const a3[] = {3};
        typedef cppx::Array_range<int const> R;
        R const ranges[] = {a0, a1, a2, a3};
        return make_vecvec( ranges );
    }
}  //  namespace my
```

Relevant support:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stddef.h>     // ptrdiff_t
#include <vector>

namespace cppx {
    using std::vector;
    typedef ptrdiff_t Size;
    typedef Size Index;

    template< class Item, Size n >
    Size n_items( Item (&)[n] ) { return n; }

    template< class Type >
    struct Non_const{ typedef Type T; };

    template< class Type >
    struct Non_const< Type const > { typedef Type T; };

    template< class Item >
    struct Array_range
    {
        Item* const p_begin;
        Item* const p_end;

        template< Size n >
        Array_range( Item (&a)[n] )
            : p_begin( a )
            , p_end( a + n )
        {}
    };

    template< class Item, Size n >
    vector<typename Non_const<Item>::T>
        make_vec( Item (&a)[n] )
    {
        return vector<typename Non_const<Item>::T>( a, a + n );
    }

    template< class Item, Size n >
    vector< vector< typename Non_const<Item>::T > >
        make_vecvec( Array_range<Item> const (&a)[n] )
    {
        typedef typename Non_const<Item>::T Nc_item;
        vector< vector< Nc_item > > result;
        for( Index i = 0; i < n; ++i )
        {
            result.push_back( vector< Nc_item >(
                a[i].p_begin, a[i].p_end
                ) );
        }
        return result;
    }
}  // namespace cppx
```

Disclaimer: (1) I just typed in the support code for this answer, fixing the direct `const`-ness issues I stumbled on. There are therefore probably reusability issues, but it shows the general idea (and it works). (2) I only compiled it with MinGW g++ (tdm64-1) 5.1.0.